# Initialize implicitly unwrapped optionals with additional parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a UIViewController with a

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
```

The `webView` will be initialized by the Interface Builder. In my `init()` it is still not being initialized.

**Assume I want to set parameters like `webView.delegate` where would I put this code such that it is only called once and called at the right time?**

Comment: @sasquatch How do I make sure that these properties are only called onces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another possibility is to use a property observer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView! {
    didSet {
        webView.delegate = self
        ...
    }
}
```

this gets called as soon as the webview gets set.

Comment: Will this set the property before or after viewDidLoa?

Comment: put some printlns into **didSet** and into **viewDidLoad** and see what happens ;)

Comment: the property observer gets called BEFORE viewdidload!

Comment: But doesn't it gets called each time property get sets, while OP wants to call just once?

Comment: it does. but this outlet only gets set once so that is perfectly fine. :)
imagine a view that is set to nil during lifecycle and reinstantiated later. if you you set its delegate in viewdidload the view that is reinstantiated later during lifecycle doesn't get its delegate set. if you use a property observer it does. see what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

The View Controller life Cycle is:

1. Preparation if being segued to
2. Outlet setting
3. didLoad, appearing and disappearing

So, in `viewDidLoad` you are sure that outlet has been setup and you can assign the delegate.

From CS193P notes:

> After instantiating and outlet-setting, viewDidLoad is called
>
> This is an exceptionally good place to put a lot of setup code.
> Its better than an init because your outlets are all set up the time it is called.

Comment: How do I make sure that these properties are only called onces?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called only once when your controller is loaded